# Rewrite Rule for 301 redirections structure

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite-module

I have developed a project where url structure has changed from the old webpage and I need to create 301 redirects to avoid SEO penalization. After reading a lot I can't find how to do this rewrites.

**Old URL**

```
/es/madrid/comprar/893134/prop-712/
```

**New URL**

```
/es/property/prop-712/
```

**Idea approach**

```
RewriteRule ^/$1/property/$5  /$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/
```

What I need is using only the first path as param (`/es/`) and the last (`/prop-712/`) to restructure the URL `/$first/property/$second` and remove the `$2`, `$3` & `$4`.

As you will see we share the last param (`prop-712`) of the URL. Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: "After reading a lot" - You must have gotten some idea - what have you tried? What are you stuck on? The regex or the directive syntax? Can you be more specific in the old URL structure... so you want to remove exactly 3 path segments after `/es/`, exactly `madrid/comprar/893134/`? Or is this variable? ie. `<alpha>/<alpha>/<number>/`?

Comment: Sorry, I have never created Rewrite rules by myself so I do not really understand how to address this, but my ideas has been the following:

RewriteRule ^/$1/property/$5  /$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/

What I need is using only the first path as param (/es/) and the last (/prop-712/) to restructure the url /$first/property/$second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following at the top of the root `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})(?:/[\w-]+){3}/([\w-]+?)/?$ https://example.com/$1/property/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect a URL of the form `/<lang>/<one>/<two>/<three>/<prop>/` (trailing slash optional) to `https://example.com/<lang>/property/<prop>/`. Where `<lang>` is any two lowercase letter language code and `example.com` is your canonical hostname. This matches exactly 3 path segments in the middle that are removed.

The regex `[\w-]+` matches each path segment, including the property (last path segment). This matches characters in the range `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) and `-` (hyphen).

Only the first and last path segments are *captured* and later referenced using the `$1` and `$2` backreferences respectively. The parenthesised subpattern in the middle (ie. `(?:/[\w-]+){3}`) that matches the 3 inner path segments is non-capturing (indicated by the `(?:` prefix).

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive, since this already occurs later in the file inside the WordPress code block.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to prevent potential caching issues. Only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect when you are sure it is working as intended.

---

A quick look at your "idea":

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/$1/property/$5  /$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/
> ```

In `.htaccess` files, the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against, does not start with a slash.

Backreferences of the form `$n` are used to reference capturing groups in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument). Backreferences can only be used in the *substitution* string (second argument)**<sup>*1</sup>**. You can't use  backreferences in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* itself (which is a standard *regex*) - the `$` carries special meaning here as an end-of-string anchor (regex syntax).

(**<sup>*1</sup>** ...and the *TestString* (first) argument of any preceding `RewriteCond` directives, but this does not apply here.)

**Reference:**

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, very useful and understandable. I always had trouble understanding the regex segments... it worked perfectly!